# Infinispan JDBC Cache Store

Tags: java, caching, jdbc, infinispan, modeshape

I want to use Infinispan JDBC Cache Store instead of LevelDb Cache Store.

Here's below my configuration:

```
<infinispan
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd
                       urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-6.0.xsd"
   xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:6.0"
   xmlns:jdbc="urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:6.0" >
    <global>
        <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" allowDuplicateDomains="true"/>
    </global>

    <!-- Define the cache loaders (i.e., cache stores). Passivation is false
     because we want *all* data to be persisted, not just what doesn't fit
     into memory. -->
    <persistence>
        <mixedKeyedJdbcStore fetchPersistentState="false" ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">
            <simpleConnection connectionUrl="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/infinispan_binary_based" driverClass="org.postgresql.Driver" username="postgres" password="postgres"/>
            <stringKeyedTable prefix="ISPN_MIXED_STR_TABLE" createOnStart="true" dropOnExit="true">
                <idColumn name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)" />
                <dataColumn name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BINARY" />
                <timestampColumn name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT" />
            </stringKeyedTable>
            <binaryKeyedTable prefix="ISPN_MIXED_BINARY_TABLE" createOnStart="true" dropOnExit="true">
                <idColumn name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)" />
                <dataColumn name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BINARY" />
                <timestampColumn name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT" />
            </binaryKeyedTable>
        </mixedKeyedJdbcStore>
    </persistence>
</namedCache>
```

but I keep getting this exception:

```
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:6.0}mixedKeyedJdbcStore'  
  at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parseElement(ParserRegistry.java:139) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]  
  at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:37) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]  
  at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser60.parsePersistence(Parser60.java:558) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
```

I removed leveldb cache store jar from my dependencies and replace it with jdbc cache store jar.

Could you tell me if I missed anything?
Help please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring a namespace called jdbc, but not using it. You need to either prefix all the tags in mixedKeyedJdbcStore with jdbc:, or use a default namespace like this:

```
<infinispan
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd
                   urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-6.0.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:6.0"
    xmlns:jdbc="urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:6.0" >
<global>
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" allowDuplicateDomains="true"/>
</global>

<!-- Define the cache loaders (i.e., cache stores). Passivation is false
 because we want *all* data to be persisted, not just what doesn't fit
 into memory. -->
<namedCache name="testCache">
    <persistence>
        <mixedKeyedJdbcStore xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:6.0" fetchPersistentState="false" ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">
            <simpleConnection connectionUrl="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/infinispan_binary_based" driverClass="org.postgresql.Driver" username="postgres" password="postgres"/>
            <stringKeyedTable prefix="ISPN_MIXED_STR_TABLE" createOnStart="true" dropOnExit="true">
                <idColumn name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)" />
                <dataColumn name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BINARY" />
                <timestampColumn name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT" />
            </stringKeyedTable>
            <binaryKeyedTable prefix="ISPN_MIXED_BINARY_TABLE" createOnStart="true" dropOnExit="true">
                <idColumn name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)" />
                <dataColumn name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BINARY" />
                <timestampColumn name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT" />
            </binaryKeyedTable>
        </mixedKeyedJdbcStore>
    </persistence>
</namedCache>
```

Your configuration was also missing a starting namedCache tag, but I assume it was a copypaste mistake, otherwise the error message would be different.

Comment: In addition to that I had a problem bundling the jdbc cache store jar in infinispan cache store. I just added the dependencies class-path in the Manifest file. Thank you.